# Why isn't the following round function rounding some numerical values?

Tags: javascript, math

This is the function:

```
export const round = (value, precision) => {
  const multiplier = Math.pow(10, precision || 0)
  return Math.round(value * multiplier) / multiplier
}
```

When I use `round` in this function:

```
SET_CAMERA_ZOOM (state, number = 0) {
  // the default is 1.4
  const cameraZoom = state.markerEditor.cameraZoom
  const roundedCameraZoom = round(cameraZoom, 1)
  state.markerEditor.cameraZoom = roundedCameraZoom + number
}
```

I get when number is `0.4`:

```
1.4
1.7999999999999998
1.8
2.2
2.6
3
```

And when number is `-0.4` (and starting from `3`):

```
2.6
2.2
1.8000000000000003
1.8
1.4
0.9999999999999999
```

Why am I getting these unrounded numbers and how to modify `round` so I get `1.8` and `1` instead?

**UPDATE:** I tried solutions from other links. Like this one:

```
precision = precision || 0
return parseFloat(parseFloat(number).toFixed(precision))
```

I still get stuff like: `0.9999999999999999`.

Comment: [*Lots of questions*](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjavascript%5D+round+to+n+significant+digits) on rounding. Does [*toFixed*](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/index.html#sec-number.prototype.tofixed) do the job?

Comment: Is this what the function shoudl do? `state.markerEditor.cameraZoom = round( state.markerEditor.cameraZoom + number, 1); `

Comment: It's all about them floating points man.

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek I couldn't find any formula there. I only saw theory.

Comment: @RobG I tried `toFixed`. I got this isn't a function error.

Comment: Surely - `return Math.round(value * multiplier / multiplier)`?

Comment: @RichardMatsen Sorry what do you mean?

Comment: Oh yeah so stupid of me.

Comment: Where are you checking the numbers? I was going for `round()` after the division.

Comment: @RobG Check my **UPDATE**.

Comment: Is there a loop somewhere? Because even if it was rounding strangely, there's no explanation as to how it goes from 1.799999 to 1.8.
We need to see the calling loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason you get numbers like `1.7999999999999998` is because of the limited precision of javascript numbers (see [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken))

So when you do things with fractions, you get results like:

```js
function round (value, precision) {
  var multiplier = Math.pow(10, precision || 0);
  return Math.round(value * multiplier) / multiplier
}

for (var i=1, x=-.4; i<5; i++) console.log(round(x*i, 1) + 1);
```

The rounding works, but as soon as you do more arithmetic (i.e. `+ 1`), you're back to the issue with limited precision.

It's much better to apply *toFixed* as the last step, so you keep precision during operations and only lose it at the end while keeping rounding, e.g.

```js
// Do arithmetic, then round as very last operation
for (var i=1, x=-.4; i<5; i++) console.log(Number((x * i + 1).toFixed(1)));
```

The use of `Number(...)` converts to number at the end to show precision and rounding are preserved.

Comment: "It's much better to apply Math.round as the last step" Sorry, but where is the correct code? I can't find it in your answer. (I'm not very sure how to apply your code to my round function).

Comment: Sorry, that should have been *toFixed*. Updated.

Answer (score 2):

The problem probably lies with your last statement

```
return Math.round(value * multiplier) / multiplier
```

you probably want this instead

```
return Math.round((value * multiplier) / multiplier)
```

or you want this

```
return Math.round(value * 10 ) / 10 // multiply by 10, round , divide
//by 10
```

You are dividing by a number which in javascript is different than an integer so unless you round the full value you are probably not going to get an integer. In Java if you perform integer division it automatically truncates a value resulting in loss of precision but javaScript is not Java, so to get the behavior you desire you need to round at the appropriate place or use multiply then divide behavior to truncate values.
Here is a link to help you understand the differences between Java and javaScript arithmetic operations https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators

Comment: I still get `1.7999999999999998` and `1.8000000000000003`.